# Typescript debugging is not working on Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging

Trying to debug an angular 4 application + .Net Core 2.0 , but when putting the breakpoints on the typescript files I get the message Breakpoints will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."  However, I hit f5 to start the app and it doesn't start until I hit f12 to bring the google chrome tools window. It is a really weird behaviour. I notice that if i delete all the breakpoints from the typescript files and hit f5 it just runs normally.

Any idea what could be the issue.

Do not know if has something to do with the map files. Map files are just into the wwwroot folder for each ts file.

Note: I am using visual studio 2017 Professional Edition

Comment: if possible, please check if the following link is helpful to you:https://medium.com/@ttemplier/how-to-debug-the-typescript-source-code-of-angular2-99a593e2983f

Comment: Thanks @Leo-MSFT. It is useful. However, my main concern is to be able to debug from visual studio 2017 which shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: (1)Run Visual Studio as an Administrator.

(2)Enable JavaScript debugging under Tools->Options->Debugging->Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE). 

Debug your app again.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks. Yes I have tried that. Turning on and off 
 that feature and restarting visual studio and the problem persists. Just realised it works if the breakpoint is put after F5 and when the page is already loaded which I don't think should be the right behaviour. right?

Comment: @D.B, Do you enable the Microsoft Symbol Servers under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols? Generally, we would add breakpoint firstly, and then debug the app, but as you said that it couldn't load the symbols, we also could debug it firstly, and then view the Debug Modules windows, load the symbols manually.

Comment: @D.B, is it related to the symbols server in your side? Could you debug your app now?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks for your support. I am still struggling with it. I tried enabling the Microsoft Symbol Server but same issue.  Just be aware that If I put the breakpoint after f5 then refresh, it gets hit.

Comment: @D.B, Is it the same issue posted by you here?https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/125941/typescript-debugging-is-not-working-on-visual-stud.html, if so, which file or which line did you add the breakpoint? I will try to debug it in my side. At least, the breakpoint was hit if I add one in main.ts file.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT. Yes it is the same issue indeed. Could you please verify if a breakpoint put before pressing f5 is hit. Well, you can put the breakpoint let's say in the app.component.ts file inside the ngOnInit() method.Thanks.

Comment: I got the same result as yours, did you get any Exception messages in your side if you enable the Exception settings under Debug menu? It seems that it doesn't really call it, since I couldn't find the output log messages.

Comment: Well, in some way it is good you got the same result. I am not getting any exceptions and all of them are enabled. I think the client-side debugging in VS 2017 is still cumbersome. Pity, Anyway Thanks for your support.

Comment: I also add a comment for you in that developer community case. The product team would view this issue and share the update. I will help you follow up it.